# Programmatically obtain WSDL for Metadata API

Tags: api, metadata, metadata-api

It seems that there is a loose typed WSDL for SOAP API - Partner WSDL

Is there something similar for Metadata API or can I get a WSDL for Metadata API programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - you can download the Metadata API WSDL by logging in to your org and clicking ***Your Name* | Setup | Develop | API | Metadata WSDL** - see the documentation on [Downloading Salesforce WSDLs and Client Authentication Certificates](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/dev_wsdl.htm) for more details.

There is no supported mechanism to get the Metadata API WSDL programmatically, but since the WSDL does not change across orgs (see [superfell](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/144/superfell)'s [comment below](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/programmatically-obtain-wsdl-for-metadata-api/1606#comment1848_1606)), just download it interactively and you should be good to go.

Comment: that'll work, but remember that its not supported, the UI is not an API

Comment: @superfell Since when did I ever worry about supportability ;-)

Comment: @metadaddy is it possible to do the same with OAuth token? I tried issuing similar request but with Authorization header set to `OAuth <token>` and I got back a redirect response to a login page.

Comment: Its been a long time since i looked at the metadata WSDL, but i'm pretty sure it doesn't change based on the org, so there's no real need to be able to programmatically access it.

Comment: As @superfell says, the metadata WSDL doesn't change across orgs, so grab it once via the UI and you should be good.

Comment: @superfell (or metadaddy) could you format your comment as an answer - this as an answer i was looking for :)

Comment: I'll edit my answer to remove the curl hack...